# Initial SessionFactory creation failed: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service

Tags: oracle, hibernate

**Seeing below error:**
2018-02-19 16:41:33,519 [main] INFO  HibernateUtil-  - Inside catch of buildsessionfactory
2018-02-19 16:41:33,520 [main] ERROR HibernateUtil-  - Initial SessionFactory creation failed: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

**code snippet:**
 try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().mergeProperties(properties).configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed: " + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

I made sure that username/pwd of db is correct in properties file; but still seeing this error. 
Any advice?

Comment: I am using oracle docker container XE ; it works fine on my friend's machine but throws error to me. Pls let me know if any more info is needed from my end.

Comment: I checked the Oracle XE 11g Error Alert logs and it has below error:
Fatal NI connect error 12170.
        TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
WARNING: inbound connection timed out (ORA-3136)

Comment: Solution:
Create sqlnet.ora:
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=300
listner.ora:
INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER = 300
Reload listener using:
23abe82:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin# lsnrctl reload